How to place a heavy bike on a workstand without lifting
My bad back makes it unsafe to lift my heavy ebike onto a workstand. Is there a way to get a heavy ebike in a work stand with the wheels off the ground and without lifting the bike.
Would the following strategy work in practice?

Roll the bike onto a dolly.
Clamp the bike onto the stand while the bike is supported by the dolly.
Remove the dolly. Now the wheels are slightly raised off the floor

Update: I am willing to spend several hundred dollars at most, ideally much less. This puts motorized workstands out of reach ☹️. I don't own my place, so I can't install anything to the ceiling for a pulley system.
My bike is a Bulls Evo TR 2 Speed in size 48.


Can you lighten the bike by removing the battery?

@Criggie alas, the bike is still very heavy without the battery

There are electric-lift workstands for exactly this situation.

@Peachy would the building owner see a bike workspace as a long-term benefit?  Are there other occupants who could use a shared space for working on their bikes ?   Nothing ventured, nothing gained.

In some countries such a ceiling lift mounting point might even fall under accessibility laws, making it necessary for the owner to allow reasonable installations.

@AndrewMorton, please post those lifting wedges as an answer.

@Willeke After some more thought, I think it would be too awkward to balance the round wheels on the pillow shapes of the wedges.

You could install a pulley in the ceiling to lift up the bike with a rope.   Preferably a second pulley with a progress capture in the wall or floor so you can let go with your hands.
With a tackle you could multiply your force to lift even very heavy objects. You could clamp into the workstand before or after lifting.
Example commercial bicycle pulley lift:
Source: https://www.containerstore.com/s/garage-and-shelving/sports-and-bike/ceiling-mount-bike-lift/12d?productId=11003969

Unfortunately I can't install anything to the ceiling/roof because I don't own my place.

Is there some kind of tall, affordable stand that I can attach the the pulley system to?

I've rephrased this as an answer because it is one.   These pulley systems are okay for storage, but the hooks can slip off especially at the saddle.  Using one to lift the bike to a workstand is something I've not tried, but it could be a viable option.   Doing work on the bike while it hangs from the pulleys is hard because it wobbles, and can fall.

@Criggie the hooks are quick and easy for storage; for work, webbing loops (pulled tight) would be more secure. It would still wobble. This could be reduced by widely spaced floor anchors/weights. I'd also be concerned about ripping the (rather small as supplied) fixings out of the ceiling in some tasks - think of how hard you have to lean on the spanner undoing cranks. You'd need to loosen stuff on the ground before lifting.

Upvoted for the mention of clamping bike to work stand instead of working it while it hangs from the cables

Expensive, but this is the answer - an ebike workstand lift (electric a cheaper one here  (not a recommendation, just a link to a product I found, there are now a number of these).
Alternately I am thinking something like a small workshop hydraulic jack, a bracket that is made fit under the bottom bracket with a foot pedal lever.

The dolly will work if there is clearance between the wheels and the dolly or if you can force the dolly out with contact.
There are rolling lifting helps, at work I use some and I have seen others as well.
You need one that holds the bike sturdy enough to lift it and roll forward and once clamped lower it enough to release the bike and roll away.
One I use at work might do but it is too expensive for that little use.
Maybe you can find one second hand in your area which works. (Not adding name or picture on purpose as many different kinds will work but the one I know might not.)
Instead of a rolling lifting aid you might be able to make a little ramp, a triangular piece of wood, onto which you push the bike, maybe one for each wheel. Think about the blocks they used to stop aircraft rolling away but less steep.
In the comments on the question someone mentioned installing a lifting system from the ceiling or a bar over your work space, which might eliminate the need for a workstand. Those are much cheaper in the simple form.

Depending on the work you intend to do a pulley system might or might not make the work stand obsolete. For jobs that do not require great force the pulley system could be enough. For everything that requires some force in directions other than more or less straight downwards, I would expect it to be quite complicated to apply force to the bike as it can sway away in any direction.

A ramp could certainly work... achieving good mechanical advantage to get your bike "up". Coupla two-by-fours and some plywood? No moving parts. Make it wide enough so that the bike will not easily slip off and either get damaged or cause you to hurt your back.

I reckon you could set up a pulley on the top of the workstand to lift its horizontal arm complete with bike (perhaps using a stirrup for hands-free lifting force). I've done something similar to make a rise and fall monitor stand (I don't think I have the parts to demonstrate properly but I'd consider mocking something up if I wasn't between a 200km ride and dinner).
Or have a set of bungee cords attached to the ceiling. Stretch them down and hook under the bike to help you lift it. That would work best if the lift isn't a large fraction of the ceiling height. The bungees should not quite lift the bike off the ground on their own, so they'd need to be quite thick. Be sure they're attached for lowering too.
Given your budget you could get a pallet truck (even a high lift one/stacker, perhaps 2nd hand) and put the workstand on that. Some come with a flat deck, for others you'd need to add it. Clamp the bike in the workstand at floor height and lift the lot. I'd want to secure the stand to the lift truck as well, as you'll have to set it up slightly overhanging. There are other lift trolleys but being more specialised they're no cheaper even if lighter duty.

This made me think about installing a transportation crossbar, using a pulley to lift up the bike, and the clamping it to the stand

Do you reckon I could hook up a pulley system  to a pull-up stand?

@Peachy yes, with the option of a single pulley (no mechanical advantage but you pull down instead of lifting) or a block and tackle (easily available with 3x or 4x mechanical advantage, so you're working against a fraction of the weight, but have to pull more rope through). If you haven't already got a workstand you could fit a workbench bike clamp to a custom crossbar on the pull up stand rather than having lots of vertical parts. Bungees would work on a pull-up stand too, if you didn't want to lift it too high (lifting the bike just a little and working from a low stool is good)

Adding as an answer more for future readers
If this was commercial you might look at a powered or geared crank, but that would be overkill for the home workshop. Example






Precis: Both show a hand-made bike workstand.  The first is a beefier version of a home rack while still being on casters and powered by a two-speed rack-and-pinion gearset, and the second is like an Acrow prop that uses a lightweight electric trailer winch to lift the bike.  Advantage of this one is that it presses between floor and ceiling without needing bolt holes.
This is not a fiscally-responsible answer for a home user, but if you're fabricating bikes or working as a bike shop, this would be a good investment.

In the cargo-bike area, there exist kickstands which have two legs and can support the bike free-standing.  One sort leaves the rear wheel resting on the ground so this doesn't help with working on the rear of the bike, but another sort is attached to the rear axle and does lift the rear wheel clear.



However we can also take inspiration from the motorcycle world.  They have bikes that are clearly too heavy to lift.  Looking over the fence shows items like:
 and has similarity to  Source: https://www.icetoolz.eu/en/icetoolz-rear-axle-bike-stand-max-29-p648/a5791

If you've got the room, it may be feasible to ramp the bike up to the workstand, clamp to the top tube, and then remove the ramp so the bike and clamp rotates on the workstand's arm.
Depends how much space you have for a ramp, and probably carpentry skills, and storage space for a fairly large and specific-purpose item.

You can easily work on the back wheel of a bike with  central a double kickstand - just weight down the front wheel. When I've had them (on a hybrid with a child seat, and on my dahon folder), a D-lock at the front is enough for that; depending on the placement of the motor and battery an e-bike might need more. The back axle type would be nice for indexing gears but gets in the way of wheel removal

This does not fully avoid lifting, but can help those who can lift some amount of weight:

Lift the front wheel of the bike and maneuver the front end of the top tube to the clamp.
Lift the back wheel and push the bike forwards until it is in balance.
Tighten clamp.

Depending on bike weight distribution, this can halve the amount of weight to be lifted. It also makes it easier to control as there is always a support point.
(You and your doctor know the condition of your back best, so play it safe and do not take unnecessary risks.)

Would a $40 hydraulic  car jack work?
Another option: if you scrounge parts from a pair of old office chairs (with pneumatic lift features), you can elevate the weight of two people, more than enough to lift a 65 lb bike.
Another idea I haven't tried yet: mount a portable chin-up bar that hangs  by padded friction under a door header, then use ratcheting tie-down strap to crank up the bike.
Postscript. The chin-up bar worked. Raising the bike is easy with the ratchet; dropping it is however  a bit tricky, but friction on the web strapping slows the descent reasonably well if one is cautious.

How would you keep the bike on the car jack while handling the lever to lift? And how would you utilize the lifting power of the chairs on the bikes? Both are options if you get them working, but I did not include the car jack in my answer as I did not see how one person could use it alone.
